# Trim() not work in PHP7

Tags: php

I wrote a short test code in PHP7:

```
<?php
  $str1=' bigapple ';
  echo strlen($str1);
  trim($str1) ;//or trim($str1," ")
  echo strlen($str1);
?>
```

But whenever I use `trim` on `$str1` ,the strlen would be return 10.
Can someone tell me the reason why? I've been searching it but find nothing.

Comment: [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) doesn't reference the variable, it returns a new one. So you need to assign it - `$new_var = trim($str1);`.

Comment: the issue is not PHP7 specific...

Comment: Keep it simple: `echo strlen(trim($str1));`

Answer (score 3):

You need to store trim string to any variable or you need to print trim string as following:

```
echo strlen(trim($str1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not assigned the trimmed value in another variable. Try as below :

```
<?php
$str1=' bigapple ';
echo strlen($str1).'<br>';
$str2 = trim($str1);
echo strlen($str2).'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: @Leon ;) Great it helped. Do accept the answer so that it can also help others.